# Wordpress plugin display query in linked file

Tags: php, html, sql, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress plugin that will query a db based off of user entered parameters and display the results in a linked html file. I can get it to display the html page, but the results variable is not passing through.

Here is how I am displaying the linked HTML file:

```
    //This is set in another location but
        $template = 'results';
    //Execute SQL
        global $wpdb;           
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    //Load template
        $content = file_get_contents( plugins_url( 'template-files/'.$template.'.php',__FILE__ ) );
        foreach ( $result as $r ){
            $contentCopy = $content;
            echo jww_display_php_file($contentCopy, $r);
        }

function jww_display_php_file( $content, $r ){
    $arr = (array)$r;
    ob_start() && extract($arr, EXTR_SKIP);
    eval('?>'.$content);
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    ob_flush();
    $content .= "<hr>";
    return $content;
}
```

Here is what I have in the HTML File:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><?php echo $Name; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `results.html` should be `results.php`, you just can't use `php` variables or functions inside an `HTML` file, so rename your file to `results.php` and then try this

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
$content = file_get_contents( plugins_url( 'template-files/results.php',__FILE__ ) );
foreach ( $result as $r ){
    $contentCopy = $content;
    echo jww_display_file($contentCopy, $r);
}

function jww_display_file( $content, $r ){
    $arr = (array)$r;
    ob_start() && extract($arr, EXTR_SKIP);
    eval('?>'.$content);
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    ob_flush();
    $content .= "<hr>";
    return $content;
}
```

Finally, inside your `results.php` file, change following

```
<td><?php echo $r->Name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $r->Age; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $r->DOB; ?></td>
```

to

```
<td><?php echo $Name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $Age; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $DOB; ?></td>
```

**Note :** `eval` is evil but it's not a problem when you are using an internal file from your server and you know the code is secure, this way, framework like `Laravel` loads a `view` file and mix variables from controller in their `MVC` framework.

Comment: Sheikh. Thank you for your answer; I have tried to implement it, but am getting an error "extract() expects parameter 1 to be array." Is there some sort of conversion I need to do to change a row of the results ($r) to an array?... I will have to look more closely at Laravel. It looks very interesting at first glance. Thank you for suggesting.

Comment: After I implemented those changes I no longer get the error, but it still does not display the anything for the $Name variable. It just displays a blank cell where it should go.

Comment: Try to debug the code, after `$arr = (array)$r;` add `print_r($arr); exit;` and see what you get.

Comment: Array ( [Name] => Aabbe [Gender] => [Origin] => Hebrew [Meaning] => Joy of the father [Age] => [DOB] => 82)

Comment: Again, `echo $content; exit;`, just before the line `$arr = (array)$r;`, at first line of the function and let me know what u see.

Comment: That displayed a table with blank values where the variable would be

Comment: Oh! my bad, it was a mistake, I missed `file_get_contents`, check the answer, I've updated it again.

Comment: I am not seeing what you changed.

Comment: At the very beginning `$content = file_get_contents(...)` on second line, it was `jww_display_file(...)`.

Comment: jww_display_file(...) was a function that builds a file string and then just returns file_get_contents, but I have taken that out now and I am still getting the same results.

Comment: Now everything is working and I've tested same thing on my localhost, make sure you coppied the whole thing properly. Also make sure sure you have `echo jww_display_file($contentCopy, $r);` in the loop. Also make sure your file path is right.

Comment: I was making other changes and testing things while working on this so I just made edit to main question with exactly what I have. It looks to me like it matches up to what you have, but am I missing something?

Comment: After `$content = file_get_contents(...)` check the content variable to make sure that your file's path is right and `$content` contains the `results.php`'s data. Put `exit($content)` just after the `$content = file_get_contents(...)` at the top portion of the code and see what you get.

Comment: You can debug it using `echo plugins_url( 'template-files/'.$template.'.php',__FILE__ )` to make sure that it's giving the right path.

Comment: Yes, I know the php file is loading because it displays it just like it should look except for the variable.

Comment: if you visit bestideabox.com enter "a" for the name and choose option contains you can see what it is doing. It displays my results.php file about 30 times. As it should since there are about 30 names with a in them. It just does not place anything where I have <?php echo $Name; ?>

Comment: Can you print `echo $Name;exit;` just right after `$arr = (array)$r;` ?

Comment: echo $Name;exit; gives a blank screen

Comment: And what `print_r($arr)` returns ?

Comment: Ok, to check it you can make an array like this `array('Name' => 'SomeName', 'Age'=>'100')` and temporarily replace the `$arr = (array)$r;` with `$arr = array('Name' => 'SomeName', 'Age'=>'100')` and check what you get.

Comment: Same results. blank value... When I enter this  $arr = array('Name' => 'SomeName', 'Age'=>'100'); echo $Name;exit; I also get blank screen

Comment: Are you sure you have `<?php echo $Name; ?>` in the `results.php` file ?

Comment: Yes this is copied right from the results.php file. "<td><?php echo $Name; ?></td>" even if I put echo $Name right under the $arr = array('Name' => 'SomeName', 'Age'=>'100') it displays nothing.

Comment: You said same result in the comment `$arr = array('Name' => 'SomeName', 'Age'=>'100'); echo $Name;exit;` I told you to replace the `$arr = (array)$r;` with `$arr = array('Name' => 'SomeName', 'Age'=>'100')` and nothing else, no echo, no exit, just everything as it this, did u make any mistake, I think you made a mistake.

Comment: Just put this line `$arr = array('Name' => 'SomeName', 'Age'=>'100');` in the place of `$arr = (array)$r;` in the function, don't put any echo or exit or anything else.

Comment: Yes that is what I did. I have //$arr = (array)$r; $arr = array('Name' => 'SomeName', 'Age'=>'100'); the echo $Name I just threw in for testing after I did what you told me and saw that it did not work

Comment: If i could see your live code then I think I could have helped you but what more i can do now. i tried to help you but sorry and the code is working in my localhost.

Comment: Yes, I am not sure why it is not working. Does your results.php file look just like mine? is your $result querying a DB? This is working inside of Wordpress. Do you think that could be affecting the results? Thank you for all your time and help. I let you know if I figure something out.

Comment: My `results.php` is `<table style="width:300px" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100px;padding:5px">Task ID</td>
    <td style="width:200px;padding:5px"><?php echo $task_id; ?></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100px;padding:5px">Name</td>
    <td style="width:200px;padding:5px"><?php echo $name; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>` variables are different and lowercased.

Comment: AH HA!!! I renamed my results.php to results.html, changed the $content = file_get_contents( plugins_url( 'template-files/'.$template.'.html',__FILE__ ) ); and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I renamed my results.php to results.html, changed the $content = file_get_contents( plugins_url( 'template-files/'.$template.'.html',FILE ) ); and it works perfectly!